# How to install Com_Overload in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I am trying to install Com_Overload Mass content generator in joomla. But I couldn't figure out how to do this.
Can anybody tell how to do this?
https://github.com/nikosdion/com_overload#version-12-august-1st-2011

Comment: Download the repo from Github, extra the folder called "component", then rezip that folder and install on Joomla

Answer (score 0):

Lodder's comment is correct, just zip up the contents of the component folder.  There is an alternative if you have [PHING](http://www.phing.info/) installed:

Download the source from
https://github.com/nikosdion/com_overload/archive/master.zip
Unzip the code onto your computer.
Run PHING from the build directory.